# Matlab: Split string into multiple strings at the points where '_' exists

Tags: string, matlab

I have a string which is this:

```
a = 'Sound_impro_Act'
```

I want to divide this into multiple strings which are the words that are seperated by `'_'` and assign these to different variables.

The end result will be like this:

```
b = 'Sound'

c = 'impro'

d = 'act'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **[`strsplit`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html)** and then **[`deal`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/deal.html)** to put them into different variables -

```
split_strings = strsplit(a,'_')
[b,c,d] = deal(split_strings{:})
```

Answer (score 5):

You may also use [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) which is faster than `strsplit`

```
a = 'Sound_impro_Act';
parts = regexp(a,'_','split');
[b,c,d] = deal(parts{:});
```

The last line comes from @Divakar's answer. Lots of thanks!

Comment: That's the fun of `S0`. I borrowed this idea of `deal` from someone else too! :)

Comment: @Divakar To be honest `deal` occured to my mind but passed away immediately; I was thinking of a way to show to OP that making alphabetized variables is not good.

Comment: Agreed on that, specially when dealing with strings.

Comment: +1 Also, `regexp` is available in older Matlab versions than `strsplit` is

Answer (score 1):

`strsplit` function can do it for you:

An example:

```
a = 'Sound_impro_Act';
b= strsplit(a, '_');
```

now you can access all splited values using `b(1), b(2), b(3)`